# Image similarity with cumulative distribution function

Tags: matlab, histogram, distribution, normal-distribution

I want ti implement in Matlab the following formula to construct a similarity matrix between input images. The similarity is the difference between cdf.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufQIM.png)

For instance, in order to compute

```
Md(1,1)=(1/Nr*Nc)*sum(sum(abs(normcdf(Id,mu,sigma)-normcdf(Iq,mu,sigma))));
```

where `mu=0` and `sigma=1`;

However, `Id` and `Iq` are downsampled grayscale images of size `64x32` and `normcdf(Id,mu,sigma)` would be always equal to 1.
from another hand, we can compute the cdf of an image from its histogram:

```
cdf(1)=hist(1);

cdf(i)=cdf(i-1)+hist(i); 2<=i<=256
```

In this case, we sum only 256 values referring to grayscale levels.

Which implementation should be done to get appropriate results?

Comment: `normcdf(Id,mu,sigma)` is not a value, its a lot of values. I also assume that if you use this, then you need Id in 0-1 range

Comment: that's it. However Id has pixel values (from 1 to 256). So, I need to compute the cdf with the histogram wich will cover 256 values then do substract and sum . I got confused because the formula does the sum over the image dimensions Nr and Nc

Comment: Are you sure that you shoul not convert to float and normalize? Most image processing/computer vision algorithm assume continuous spaces and work with double 0-1 images

Comment: No, the input images are of type 'single' and are preprocessed (downsampled and patch-normalized) to produce `64x32`snapshots with single values rounded to integers.

Comment: Either you need to normalize them to 0-1 or your mu and sigma are wrong. Thats it

Comment: Is it correct to divide all the pixel values by `Nr*Nc` then work with `mu=0 ` and `sigma=1`?

Comment: No, divide the pixels by max(Id), 255 in your case

Comment: ok thank you so much for these clarifications